# Create Microsoft teams meeting through API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

In Azure Active Directory I've registered a new app and given it the `Read and create online meetings` permissions. I've granted admin consent for the permission and now I'm trying to create a meeting through the command line.

I generated a client secret for the app.

Then I'm requesting a access token using my tenant GUID, client ID of the app and client secret I generated. This gives me back a jwt. When I decode the JWT amongst the roles I can see `"OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All"` which gives me hope that I can actually create meetings using this bearer token.

[image]

I then send a POST request to  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my-user-guid>/onlineMeetings`
with the following body:

```
  {
   "startDateTime":"2021-03-16T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
   "endDateTime":"2021-03-16T15:03:30.8566356-07:00",
   "subject":"Application Token Meeting",
   "participants": {
     "organizer": {
       "identity": {
         "user": {
           "id": "<my-user-guid>"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and the response comes back with

```
"code": "Forbidden",
"message": "Application does not have permission to Create online meeting on behalf of this user.",
```

Am I missing something?

Edit:
As some of the comments have suggested I should create an application access policy. So I'm following the documentation which asks me to `Connect using admin credentials`

When i run `Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userCredential` with my account it fails with the following error:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed: Accessing WS metadata exchange failed: Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed: Accessing WS metadata exchange failed
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: : Unknown error
```

But this is what is confusing me. I don't really know if I'm trying to login with the correct account. I'm using my personal account on azure which is (afaik) not a business account with skype for business.
I'm running the commands to log in on the azure portal's PowerShell interface. Am I supposed to run this on my local machine instead?
I think I'm not fully understanding what all of the moving parts are that need configuration.
Can I add those application Access Policies in the azure portal interface somewhere?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of your parsing token.

Comment: What do you mean with parsing token? I'm not sure where to find this

Comment: Have you created an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy)?

Comment: To parse the token is to decode the jwt.

Comment: @CarlZhao I've not been able to add the application policy. I've edited my question with further information. Thank you.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the parsed JWT

Comment: You cannot use a personal account, you need to use a work account with an administrator role.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense why it's not working then. So i created a new account in my active directory (which i assume is a work account at that point) trying to go through the steps of the application access policy i get the error `Connect-MicrosoftTeams: password_required_for_managed_user: Password is required for managed user` which has me stumped again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), make sure you grant the **OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All** `application permission` to the application. Then you need to use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain an access token.

Please note that when you create an online meeting with an application token, administrators must create an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) and grant it to a user, authorizing the app configured in the policy to create an online meeting on behalf of that user (user ID specified in the request path).

Comment: Hmm, yes i've seen this documentation as well but i think this is where i'm stuck. When i follow those steps i fail to connect to the admin. I'll add some info to my question.

Comment: @Enermis -  from the info from question i see you are using different command to access permissions. Could you please follow step 4 in [Configure application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy) to grand the permission on behalf user.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I'm unable to get to this point in the documentation because it requires me to `Connect to Skype for Business PowerShell with an administrator account` which i'm unable to do

Comment: Yes , it require the admin account.